# Partition data and plot each set as a different color

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color, partitions

```
data = { {2, 60}, {4.5, 62}, {6.5, 64}, {8, 65}, {9, 65}, {10, 
  65}, {11, 65}, {12, 67}, {13, 67}, {14, 67}, {16, 67}, {17, 
  67}, {18, 67}, {19, 65}, {20, 64}, {21, 70}, {22, 75}, {23, 
  80}, {24, 80}, {25, 82}, {26, 82}, {27, 79}, {30, 80}}

ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {"T(Celcius)", "Volume Collected"}]
```

I want to partition the data into three pieces, and the plot produced should have the points joined with a line that corresponds to the color of the point.

Comment: One question remains: how do you want to partition your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Evaluate[
  Cases[data, {a_ /; #[[1]] <= a <= #[[2]], __}] & /@ 
   Partition[{0, 10, 20, 30}, 2, 1]], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick], 
 AxesLabel -> {"T(Celcius)", "Volume Collected"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could use `ColorFunction` option . The following colors plot by paritioning of x-axis. You could choose your own function:

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, 
   Which[0 < x < 10, Red, 10 <= x < 20, Green, x >= 20, Blue]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> 10, MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image]

An alternative for partitioning x-values using `MeshShading`:

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> {{10, 20}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't said how to partition the data but to automate on the basis of the length of the list you can do this:

```
segment = Ceiling[Length[data]/3];

ListPlot[Partition[data, segment+1, segment, 1, {}], Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"T(Celcius)", "Volume Collected"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{2, 60}, {4.5, 62}, {6.5, 64}, {8, 65}, {9, 65}, {10, 
    65}, {11, 65}, {12, 67}, {13, 67}, {14, 67}, {16, 67}, {17, 
    67}, {18, 67}, {19, 65}, {20, 64}, {21, 70}, {22, 75}, {23, 
    80}, {24, 80}, {25, 82}, {26, 82}, {27, 79}, {30, 80}};
```

---

I will present a few variations and hopefully the readers can decide what works best for their needs.

*Using built in `ColorData`:*

This is a starting point. It colors the line using the specified gradient scheme from start to finish.

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][x]]]
```

[image]

---

*User defined color function with continuous change:*

To color continuously in three user-defined colors from start to finish:

```
cf1[x_] := Blend[{Red, Blue, Green}, x];
ListLinePlot[data, ColorFunction -> (cf1[#1] &)]
```

[image]

---

*User defined color function with arbitrary boundaries:*

To color in discrete steps, define a `ColorFunction` using `If`. Here the cut off points are arbitrarily chosen as `8` and `15` for color boundaries.

```
cf2[x_] := If[x <= 8, Red, If[8 < x < 15, Blue, Darker@Green]]

ListLinePlot[data
 , ColorFunction -> (cf2[#1] &)
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , GridLines -> {{8, 15}, None}
 , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dashed}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

---

Instead of a mere color change, if data has to be partitioned and presented as such, it needs to be overlapped by one data point for it to appear continuous. e.g.

```
dnewOverlap = Partition[data, UpTo[9], 8]
ListLinePlot[dnewOverlap]
```

or

```
ListLinePlot[dnewOverlap, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker@Green}]
```

[image]

Interested readers can add the option `Mesh -> All` to all plots to see the results.